# jQuery regex for username

Tags: php, jquery, regex

I want to implement a regex for usernames with the following conditions:

1. The username will consist of only a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and - (hyphen);
2. The username shall not consist of ONLY digits or ONLY hyphens but it can have only characters;
3. The first & last characters shouldn't be hyphens (it can be digits but not entirely digits);
4. Also, there shouldn't be 2 hyphens back to back;
5. Minimum number of chars is 5 and max is 25;

So far I have tried this regex:

```
var filter = /(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{5,25}$)^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$/;
```

It achieves conditions 1, 3, 4 and 5 correctly. But it doesn't fully satisfy condition 2. In my regex, it makes sure it doesn't consist entirely of hyphens. But it does allow only digits, which it shouldn't.

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong or what needs to be done. Explanation of regex will be appreciated.

Comment: If you could let the username contain full stops too, I'd consider it a personal favour ;-)

Comment: instead of going for one massively ugly and utterly unmaintainble franken-regex, why not just use a multi-stage validation process? with a single regex you can at most say "it doesn't pass". with multi stage you can say "not enough digits" "too many dashes", blah blah blah.

Comment: i agree with u @marc-b but am not sure how to achieve that

Comment: `if (test1(...)) { 'fails test 1'} if (test2(...)) { 'fails test 2' }`. it's not rocket science.

Comment: alright @marc-b will try that too :)

Comment: Every extra requirement you publicly require reduces the security of your passwords as everyone knows not to bother trying to crack all numeric passwords. There is no legitimate reason to say you cant use all punctuation symbols either

Comment: While I totally agree with you, no-one has mentioned passwords.

Comment: @Anigel, this is for usernames, not passwords.

Comment: Apologies I can see that now, end of the day and not reading straight

Comment: haha @Anigel we understand ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a negative lookahead at the beginning. I also placed the `^` anchor at the beginning of the expression.

```
^(?![0-9]+$)(?=[a-zA-Z0-9-]{5,25}$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+(-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This prevents against a match of `^[0-9]+$` which is in other words, a string with only numbers.

Comment: In case someone needs help visualizing this:  http://www.debuggex.com/i/6ne8Y_2bNWkxO_d6.png

Answer (score 5):

For maintainability, things like this are usually better written as a series of tests rather than one big test.

```
var filter = function (username) {
    var allDigits = /^[0-9]+$/g,
        allHyphens = /^[-]+$/g, //doesn't need a character class, but I find it's more readable
        multiHyphens = /[-]+/g,
        startsWith = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{1}/,
        endsWith = /[A-Za-z0-9]{1}$/
        hasInvalidChars = /[^A-Za-z0-9-]/,
        meetsReqs = false;
    if (username.length >= 5 || username.length <= 25) { //ensure correct length
        meetsReqs = !allDigits.test(username);
        meetsReqs = meetsReqs && !allHyphens.test(username);
        meetsReqs = meetsReqs && !multiHyphens.test(username);
        meetsReqs = meetsReqs && !hasInvalidChars.test(username);
        meetsReqs = meetsReqs && startsWith.test(username);
        meetsReqs = meetsReqs && endsWith.test(username);
    }
    return meetsReqs;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work in a quick test on my computer:

```
^(?![^-]*--+)(?![0-9]+$)[a-zA-Z0-9][-a-zA-Z0-9]{3,23}[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Explanation

```
^(?![^-]*--+)  No double (or more) hyphens
(?![0-9]+$)    Digits only forbidden
[a-zA-Z0-9]    Starts with a-z A-Z or 0-9
[-a-zA-Z0-9]{3,23}  Three to 23 more characters, including hyphens
[a-zA-Z0-9]$    Ends with a-z A-Z or 0-9
```

So that's 1 + (3 to 23) + 1 characters, ie 5 to 25.